# Start Tightvncserver service in raspberry

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to start tightvncserver but I can't get the service name right

I tried

```
service tightvncserver start
```

and

```
service tightvnc start
```

and

```
service vncserver start
```

but all i get is unrecognized device. i tried service --status-all but the tightvnc is not listed.

Comment: just enter `tightvncserver` in terminal or on `ssh`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run tightvncserver then in the command terminal you would type in vncserver. I believe you may have to specify the port as well.

To do that you type in :

vncserver :1

where 1 is the port that you are going to use. I just stick with the default on mine. Are you looking have vncserver start up on boot? If so you need to add in a script that will run the server on start up. If you don't you will have to start vncserver each time the pi is restarted. I will look for that script and add it onto this answer when I find it. Hopefully that helps.